# Does anything in RAGE's multiplayer mode unlock anything in the single-player campaign?

Tags: rage

Does anything in *RAGE's* multiplayer mode unlock anything in the single-player campaign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't played much multiplayer myself yet, but extensive searching has turned up nothing so far.

So far as I know, multiplayer mode doesn't unlock anything in the single player campaign.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it does.

Multiplayer cooperative is a bunch of side missions that you hear mentioned in the main story.   The versus games are 6 man vehicle based matches.